# Prove: $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-m \cos^2 x)(1+ m \sin^2x)}}=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-m^2 \sin^2 x}}$ for $0\le m<1$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

How to prove the following identity? For $0\le m<1$,
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-m \cos^2 x)(1+ m \sin^2x)}}=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-m^2 \sin^2 x}}$$
Then it will be an elliptic integral.

Firstly, the objects in the squre root are not equal, so it cann't be solved just by Trigonometric Identities.

Comment: Trigonometric identities are not enough, and coordinate change is not enough, but perhaps both combined?...

Comment: One approach is to expand the integrand as a power series in $m$ and integrate term by term and then compare the coefficients on both sides. But this is bit tricky to handle when dealing with the integrand in LHS.

Comment: I updated my answer to get rid of any unnecessary details. You may have second look at it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $$I(a, b) =\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^{2}\cos^{2}x+b^{2}\sin^{2}x}}\tag{1}$$ then it is easy to observe that $$cI(ac, bc)=I(a, b) \tag{2}$$ Using the substitution $b\tan x=t$ in $(1)$ we see that $$I(a, b) =\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{(t^{2}+a^{2})(t^{2}+b^{2})}}\tag{3}$$ The integral on the right hand side of the identity in question is a complete elliptic integral of first kind and is commonly denoted by $K(m)$. It is almost obvious from equation $(1)$ that $$K(m) =I(1, \sqrt{1-m^{2}})\tag{4}$$ Using substitution $\tan x=t$ we can see that the left hand side of the identity in question is equal to $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{(t^{2}+1-m)(1+(1+m)t^{2})}}=\frac{I(1/\sqrt{1+m},\sqrt{1-m})}{\sqrt{1+m}}=I(1,\sqrt{1-m^{2}})$$ (via equations $(2)$ and $(3)$). The proof is now complete via equation $(4)$.

Comment: (+1) Beautiful answer (as expected). I would add that OP's claim "*cannot be solved by trigonometric substitution*" is not true, strictly speaking, since $K(m)=\frac{\pi}{2\,\text{AGM}(1,\sqrt{1-m^2})}$ can be proved through [Lagrange's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity) and a suitable substitution.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I was in a hurry so I gave the link to my blog. The identity can be proved just via trigonometric substitution. I will update my answer to fix this a bit later. Now is sleep time here.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I could not resist the temptation to fix my answer as soon as possible for me. The updated answer just uses basic trigonometric substitutions and nothing more.

Comment: Very nice, I would give you an extra (+1), but I cannot :)